# Insert records based on query (oracle, sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, oracle12c

I have some records:

```
select f1.id, f1.value from table1 f1
minus
select f2.id, f2.value from table2 f2;
```

[image]

I need to instert this all records to the new table:
[image]

How can I do it?
As value for new col will be just varchar = "col1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use insert from select statement

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, ... column_n )
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM source_table
[WHERE conditions];
```

**Update:**
According to your case, try this:

```
insert into new_table (id, new_col, value) 
select id, 'col1', value from 
 (select f1.id, f1.value from table1 f1
  minus
  select f2.id, f2.value from table2 f2)
```

Comment: but where to put my query with minus?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
(id, new_col, val )
SELECT id, 'col1', col2
FROM old_table;
```

Note: Single inverted in `col1`-> select value as col1 and not in `col2` -> select column value i.e. True/False